# how to recognize paragraph in a text by regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I'm writing a software that converts Text to HTML and also I use the regular expression. I wanna know how to identify paragraph in the body of text?
I wrote a snippet of code for identifying paragraph, for example, in this text, it just identifies "my" word.To identify a paragraph, I look for text that has double spaces before and after it.

> Hi
>
> my name is radamal shera.

```
   private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string inputText = txtInput.Text;   


       string pattern = @"(\r\n)([a-zA-Z]+)";

        Match result = Regex.Match(txtInput.Text, pattern);
        if (result.Success)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("match : {0}", result.Value);
        }


    }
```

Comment: You could `Regex.Split` with `(?:\r\n?|\n){2,}` regex to get all the "paragraphs"..

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, you rock!, it works fine. thanks a lot

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But, there is a problem at the moment, "Hi" is a title it's not a paragraph.I can't identify paragraph with split method.I just wanna "my name is radamal shera."

Comment: The remove that line before applying the `Regex.Split`. Is the first line always a title?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my text is random and it depends on user input in my program.because maybe we don't a title in text.

Comment: Then what is the criterion for the title?

Comment: You should search Wikipedia for the definition of a _paragraph_ before you continue. It's fairly complex and not at all what you'd think.

Answer (score 3):

Since you plan to get substrings between 2 or more line breaks, you may use `Regex.Split` with the following regex:

```
(?:\r\n?|\n){2,}
```

See [th regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5cr%5cn%3f%7c%5cn%29%7b2%2c%7d&i=Hi%0d%0a%0d%0amy+name+is+radamal+shera.)

**Details**:

- `(?:\r\n?|\n){2,}` - 2 or more (`{2,}`) occurrences of:

  - `\r\n?` - CR and an optional LF
  - `|` - or
  - `\n` - a newline (LF)

[image]

To remove the first line you may consume it and split the rest:

```
var pars = Regex.Split(s, @"^.*[\r\n]*|(?:\r\n?|\n){2,}")
  .Where(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m))
  .ToList();
```